# Output .obj or other format once per line

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm exporting a `.obj` file, but when I open it, it is all jumbled up. I need to have it like this:

> v 1 1 1
>   v 1 1 1

not like

> v 1 1 1v1 1 1

Is this possible?

Comment: Please add more information, your question is unclear.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean by the codes you have used. Could you provide a screenshot of your problem and describe what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

My default cube exports to obj just as you wish...

[image]

it has just a LF, though not CR+LF (being on linux) maybe your text editor expects CR+LF to recognize new lines: try to see if it supports unix line endings (just LF), or replace LF with CR+LF somehow...